# ListView Adapter's getView() not working properly

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

Using ViewHolder pattern in adapter, I'm listing some categories in ListView. The code is working fine untill I'm not scrolling the ListView. To quickly observe the problem, have a look on the screen shot...

[image]

**ListActivity.class**

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    Map<String, String> vehicleDetails = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    vehicleDetails.put("Chassis Number", "UVXZ123TR3546");
    vehicleDetails.put("Engine Number", "12332-WF1231");
    vehicleDetails.put("Model Number", "MODEL ONE OF TRUCK");
    vehicleDetails.put("Vehicle Type", "FARM TRUCK");

    Map<String, String> dealerDetails = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    dealerDetails.put("Dealer Name", "Mr. Abcd Pqrstuv");
    dealerDetails.put("Dealer Contact Number", "1234567890");
    dealerDetails.put("Dealer Contact Number 2", "0987654321");

    Map<String, String> driverDetails = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    driverDetails.put("Driver Name", "Mr. Xyz Abcdefg");
    driverDetails.put("Driver Contact Number 1", "1234567890");
    driverDetails.put("Driver Contact Number 2", "0987654321");

    Map<String, String> yardDetails = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    yardDetails.put("Yard Code", "YARD - 6");
    yardDetails.put("Plant", "P-2134");
    yardDetails.put("Storage Location", "1000");
    yardDetails.put("Zone Code", "1");
    yardDetails.put("Bay Number", "2");

    Map<String, String> vehicleStatus = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    vehicleStatus.put("Dispatch Date", "12 Jan 2016 00:00:00");
    vehicleStatus.put("Estimated Delivery Date", "12 Feb 2016 00:00:00");
    vehicleStatus.put("Delivery Date", "13 Feb 2016 00:00:00");
    vehicleStatus.put("Status", "Delivered");

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    data.put("Vehicle Details", vehicleDetails);
    data.put("Dealer's Details", dealerDetails);
    data.put("Yard Details", yardDetails);
    data.put("Driver's Details", driverDetails);
    data.put("Vehicle Status", vehicleStatus);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_category_list, data));
  }
}
```

**CategoryAdapter.class**

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final int layoutId;
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> data;
    private Map<String, String> map;

    public CategoryAdapter(Activity context, int layoutId, Map<String, Map<String, String>> data) {
        super(context, layoutId);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutId = layoutId;
        this.data = data;
        this.map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.table = (TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.table);
            viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String title = new ArrayList<>(data.keySet()).get(position);
        viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(title);

        map.clear();
        map = data.get(title);
        ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());

        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(context);

            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            linearLayout.setPadding(4, 10, 4, 10);

            TextView txtKey = new TextView(context);
            txtKey.setTextSize(17);
            txtKey.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            txtKey.setText(keys.get(i));

            TextView txtValue = new TextView(context);
            txtValue.setTextSize(15);
            txtValue.setText(map.get(keys.get(i)));

            linearLayout.addView(txtKey);
            linearLayout.addView(txtValue);

            row.addView(linearLayout);
            viewHolder.table.addView(row);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TableLayout table;
        private TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

**category_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    style="@style/DetailCardView"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle" style="@style/DetailGroupTitleText" android:text="TITLE" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now the issue is in `getView()` method. It is giving unexpected results I mean Vehicle Details are coming with Yard Details Or Driver Details are listed in Vehicle status and something like this. This is happening only when I'm scrolling the ListView otherwise everything is fine. 
Please help me How can I fix this situation?

Downvoters! Please keep calm yaar, I really want help...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, Copy and paste/replace your code.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.table = (TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.table);
        viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    String title = new ArrayList<>(data.keySet()).get(position);
    viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(title);

    map.clear();
    map = data.get(title);
    final ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        final TableRow row = new TableRow(context);

        final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setPadding(4, 10, 4, 10);

        final TextView txtKey = new TextView(context);
        txtKey.setTextSize(17);
        txtKey.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txtKey.setText(keys.get(i));

        final TextView txtValue = new TextView(context);
        txtValue.setTextSize(15);
        txtValue.setText(map.get(keys.get(i)));

        linearLayout.addView(txtKey);
        linearLayout.addView(txtValue);

        row.addView(linearLayout);
        viewHolder.table.addView(row);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not Working... Even you are assigning value to a final field convert view

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that `getView` calls every time `ListView` needs to get a new item after scroll. This means your loop with filling by new views repeated without cleaning older one. I guess it is reason of your problem, so you should clear your `TableRow` from result if it is contained there.

Comment: if I remove all children from my TableLayout then it will be re-filled by another Map's values..